# How use the combobox keydown event without selecting the listed item

Tags: vba, excel, drop-down-menu, combobox, keydown

I have in my Excel VBA project, a combobox which uses a range of cells as it's list of items. I have used a filter in it, so that whenever a value is entered, the list shrinks down to the items containing the string, and dropdown list is shown. However, the problem appears, when the dropdown is shown, the navigation keys can't be used to scroll within the items. As soon as the down key is pressed the dropdown list will be filtered again.

I guess its happening because the down key while focusing on the items, is also selecting it. Hence, the combobox_change event is called automatically.

Is there a way so that I can stop the keydown event automatically selecting an item, but only scroll through them?

Comment: if you list is ordered, combobox will automatically suggest the next valid option.. you wouldn't need a filter for that. but in anyway if you want to have that filter function and keydown event, you could exclude the navigation keys in your keyDown event. either with a if or select case... if not KeyCode = 48 then ..

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I already tried that, but the problem is not resolved. Vba automatically selects the item when it is focused using the down key. Is there any way I could stop that?

Answer (score 5):

*Edited Answer:*

Now having built my own sheet and worked with these ideas, ironically `Application.EnableEvents` only helps in certain situations because the `Combobox_Change()` event still fires with events disabled (or seems to be the case, at least). The basic idea that I found involved manipulating the `KeyCodes` and setting flags. My example below involves using a `ComboBox` called `TempCombo` and running code after the `TempCombo_KeyDown()` event within the VBA for the sheet (I have trimmed my stuff down for example purposes):

```
Option Explicit
Dim Abort as Boolean

Private Sub TempCombo_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case 38  'Up
            If TempCombo.ListIndex <= 0 Then KeyCode = 0 'ignore "Up" press if already on the first selection, or if not on a selection
            Abort = True
            If Not KeyCode = 0 Then ' If on a selection past the first entry
                KeyCode = 0
            'Manually choose next entry, cancel key press
                TempCombo.ListIndex = TempCombo.ListIndex - 1
            End If
            Me.TempCombo.DropDown
        Case 40 'Down
            If TempCombo.ListIndex = TempCombo.ListCount - 1 Then Keycode = 0 
        ' This method was from the discussion I linked, prevents "falling off the bottom of the list"
            Abort = True
            If Not KeyCode = 0 Then ' If on a selection before the last entry
                KeyCode = 0
            'Manually choose next entry, cancel key press
                TempCombo.ListIndex = TempCombo.ListIndex + 1
            End If
            Me.TempCombo.DropDown
    End Select
    Abort = False
End Sub

Private Sub TempCombo_Change()
    If Abort Then Exit Sub ' Stop Event code if flag set
    Abort = True
    ' sets the flag until finished with commands to prevent changes made by code triggering the event multiple times
    
    ' ~~~ Insert Code you want to run for other cases here ~~~

    Abort = False
End Sub
```

I used the `Abort` variable as a flag in the `TempCombo_Change()` to prevent both multiple firings of the event code, and allow keys to not change the text result of the linked cell, preventing my dynamic range from updating. Make sure both subroutines are on the sheet where the `ComboBox` is!

So that is a skeleton of what I did for this, if someone finds a problem let me know, but I hope this can help someone.

---

> *Old Answer*
>
> I'm not sure how much this will truly help, and if I had the
> reputation I would just submit this as a comment because this really doesn't
> qualify as an answer. However I had the same question and stumbled across
> a thread trying to answer this. I hope that one of the codes on
> one of Microsoft's help pages: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-customize/disable-userform-combobox-change-event-when-arrow/598b44a1-dcda-4a2c-8e12-2b84762f98ae?db=5
>
> It seems that looking at the `KeyDown` events for the up and down arrows
> and pairing with the `ComboBox_Change` events would allow you to isolate
> them and then prevent the combobox from updating when you press up and down
> to navigate the list.
>
> I recommend looking through the OP's follow up post, it is incredibly
> informative and helped me adapt to my own case.
> Also note differences between `UserForm` and general Excel VBAcode, for
> instance `Me.EnableEvents` for `UserForm` would need to be
> `Application.EnableEvents` for general excel!
>
> I know this is old now, but in case this helps anyone, good luck!