# Stop combobox autoselecting upon arrow down

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have an ActiveX control combobox in Excel that takes as filters a list of strings by characters typed in the box, where the user then selects the item he/she is searching for. I would like the combobox to allow typing a character, and having the user be able to use the down and up arrows on the keyboard to scan through the list of items in the dropdown. However, when the user uses the down arrow key, the first item in the dropdown is selected and then is the only item remaining.

Also, I would like to be able to use the scroll wheel if possible inside the dropdown list, and have the list sort such that when typing in `am,` items starting with `a` are displayed first.

Please let me know if there's something I can do to avoid that behavior.

Here is the code for the combobox:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChangePrior(ByVal Target As Range)
    cLstPrior = Application.Transpose(Database.UsedRange.Columns(1)) 'set module-level variable
    Tool.priorCmb.List = cLstPrior        'initialize ComboBox to range Col A (UsedRange only)
    Tool.priorCmb.ListIndex = -1     'set ComboBox value to empty
End Sub

Private Sub priorCmb_Change()
   filterComboListPrior Tool.priorCmb, cLstPrior
End Sub

Private Sub priorCmb_KeyPress(ByVal keyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    Tool.priorCmb.DropDown
End Sub

Private Sub priorCmb_GotFocus()   'or _MouseDown()
    Tool.priorCmb.DropDown
End Sub

Public Sub filterComboListPrior(ByRef cmbPrior As ComboBox, ByRef dLstPrior As Variant)
    Dim itmPrior As Variant, lstPrior As String, selPrior As String

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With cmbPrior
        selPrior = .Value
        If IsEmpty(cLstPrior) Then cLstPrior = Database.UsedRange.Columns(1)
        For Each itmPrior In cLstPrior
            If Len(itmPrior) > 1 Then If InStr(1, itmPrior, selPrior, 1) Then lstPrior = lstPrior & itmPrior & "||"
        Next
        If Len(lstPrior) > 1 Then .List = Split(Left(lstPrior, Len(lstPrior) - 2), "||") Else .List = dLstPrior
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with the same issue, and ended up finding some info on a Microsoft Help-site thread that let me play around with it. [I posted an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26931436/how-use-the-combobox-keydown-event-without-selecting-the-listed-item/34621918#34621918) which seems to work for me. Seems like a bunch of us have had this issue! The answer is a stripped down version of what I use in a sheet for this same concept. I take it your ComboBox is called `priorCmb`, so I'm going to reference that for the events

The basic idea involves the `priorCmb_KeyDown()` event in the sheet where the combobox is located (though should be similar to `KeyPress` in overall behavior except using `KeyCode` instead of `keyAscii`, so adapt accordingly). This can grab the arrow key presses and set a flag. The keys' actions are bypassed by setting the `KeyCode` value to 0 and using an increment/decrement with the `priorCmb.ListIndex` value to change the selection. Then, using a flag in the `priorCmb_Change()` event, you can prevent the ComboBox from changing the linked cell value due to the up and down arrows. Once you get to the end of your `KeyDown` or `KeyPress` event, you can reset the flag for when you want changes to occur.

*The reason I force the change in the code, rather than let it happen at the end of the `Key_Down` event (in my case, or `KeyPress` in yours), is that I can set the flag and run the `_Change()` event for the combobox with the flag set to prevent the change code from running. Then at the end of the `Key`event I turn off the flag for any other changes from the user. Because the `KeyCode` is 0 (or `keyAscii` equivalent) there, it will not run anything at the end of the function, and thus not update the code again.*

Hope that helps, there is a link in that answer to the thread I found, which has some general ideas (though focused on UserForms instead of spreadsheets, so again adapt accordingly, though I have a note in the linked post about that). Good luck!

Note: Those parts of code were what seemed to control this behavior in my sheet, but if you have an issue with getting it to work, I can look at it again.