# Stop dropdown selection from autofilling combobox

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have an ActiveX combobox that has a dropdown which is populated and filtered when a user types characters into the combobox. The dropdown items are from `cLst`. So the dropdown will be open, but as soon as the user hits the arrow down, the combobox populates with the first dropdown item and all of the other items in the dropdown disappear, because it then tries to filter the dropdown by the item in the combobox, which is an exact match for one item in the dropdown (the one that was highlighted upon arrow down).

How can I avoid this autofilling behavior when arrowing down through the dropdown, and have the user hit enter on the selection they want to populate the combobox instead?

If the user avoids using the keyboard, the mouse works fine to scroll through and highlight, then click, and only populates the combobox upon the click. I would like the scroll wheel to work if possible to scroll through the dropdown.

```
Private Sub newCmb_Change()
   filterComboList Tool.newCmb, cLst
End Sub

Private Sub newCmb_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    Tool.newCmb.DropDown
End Sub

Private Sub newCmb_GotFocus()   'or _MouseDown()
    Tool.newCmb.DropDown
End Sub

Public Sub filterComboList(ByRef cmb As ComboBox, ByRef dLst As Variant)
    Dim itm As Variant, lst As String, sel As String, rng As Range
    With Worksheets("Database")
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(.UsedRange.Rows(2), .Cells.Resize(.Columns.Count - 1).Offset(1))
    End With

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With cmb
        sel = .Value
        If IsEmpty(cLst) Then cLst = rng
        For Each itm In cLst
            If Len(itm) > 1 Then If InStr(1, itm, sel, 1) Then lst = lst & itm & "||"
        Next
        If Len(lst) > 1 Then .List = Split(Left(lst, Len(lst) - 2), "||") Else .List = dLst
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same issue, and ended up finding some info on a Microsoft Help-site thread that let me play around with it. [I posted an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26931436/how-use-the-combobox-keydown-event-without-selecting-the-listed-item/34621918#34621918) which seems to work for me. It is a stripped down version of what I use in a sheet for this same concept.

The basic idea involves the `newCmb_KeyDown()` event (though should be similar to `KeyPress` in overall behavior) in the sheet that the combobox is located in, which snags the arrow key presses and sets a flag. The keys' actions are canceled by setting the `KeyCode` value to 0 and changing the `newCmb.ListIndex` value by +/-1 to change the selection, and using a flag in the `newCmb_Change()` event you can prevent the ComboBox from changing the linked cell value due to the up and down arrows. Once you get to the end of your `KeyDown` or `KeyPress` event, you can reset the flag for when you want changes to occur.

Hope those help, there is a link in that answer to the thread I found, which has some general ideas (though focused on UserForms instead of spreadsheets). Good luck!

**Edit
Note: Those parts of code were what seemed to control this behavior in my sheet, but if you have an issue with getting it to work, I can look at it again.