# How to switch between items of ActiveX Combobox with arrow keys

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, activex

How to switch between item of ActiveX Combobox with arrow keys? I would like to achieve this behavior generated with mouse hovering over item. So that the blue highlight moves as we press down arrow or up arrow key.

[image]

I have a clue that it should be done with the CoboboxName_KeyDown event.

```
Private Sub TempCombo_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case 38 'up
        Case 40 'down
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manipulating `TempCombo.ListIndex` is the answer. Example for `up arrow` key:

```
Case 38  'Up
TempCombo.ListIndex = TempCombo.ListIndex - 1
Me.TempCombo.DropDown
```

Using it requires error handling for first and last item on the list. Here is a hint to solve the problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34621918/1903793