# UserForm ComboBox with searchable list to not select first item with keyDown

Tags: excel, vba, userform

**Background**

I have a UserForm with a ComboBox (`ComboBox1`) that includes a searchable list (thanks to the code). However, when I use the down button, it just selects the first item and gets rid of the rest of the list that was there first (like as if basically puts the first item as the searched name).

I have found a very similar question on stack overflow but the solution did not fully work for me.

Here is the link: [How use the combobox keydown event without selecting the listed item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26931436/how-use-the-combobox-keydown-event-without-selecting-the-listed-item)

The code that I have for my UserForm is below:

```
Dim a()

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  a = [Liste].Value
  Me.ComboBox1.List = a
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
Dim Abort As Boolean
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case 38  'Up
            If ComboBox1.ListIndex <= 0 Then KeyCode = 0 'ignore "Up" press if already on the first selection, or if not on a selection
            Abort = True
            If Not KeyCode = 0 Then ' If on a selection past the first entry
                KeyCode = 0
            'Manually choose next entry, cancel key press
                ComboBox1.ListIndex = ComboBox.ListIndex - 1
            End If
            Me.ComboBox1.DropDown
        Case 40 'Down
            If ComboBox1.ListIndex = ComboBox1.ListCount - 1 Then KeyCode = 0
        ' This method was from the discussion I linked, prevents "falling off the bottom of the list"
            Abort = True
            If Not KeyCode = 0 Then ' If on a selection before the last entry
                KeyCode = 0
            'Manually choose next entry, cancel key press
                ComboBox1.ListIndex = ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1
            End If
            Me.ComboBox1.DropDown
    End Select
    Abort = False
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
If Abort Then Exit Sub ' Stop Event code if flag set
    Abort = True
    ' sets the flag until finished with commands to prevent changes made by code triggering the event multiple times
Set d1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    tmp = UCase(Me.ComboBox1) & "*"
    For Each c In a
        If UCase(c) Like tmp Then d1(c) = ""
    Next c
    Me.ComboBox1.List = d1.keys
    Me.ComboBox1.DropDown
Abort = False
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  ActiveCell = Me.ComboBox1
  Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
  Unload Me
End Sub
```

The particular section that is apparently trying to stop the comboBox from selecting the first item is this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
Dim Abort As Boolean
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case 38  'Up
            If ComboBox1.ListIndex <= 0 Then KeyCode = 0 'ignore "Up" press if already on the first selection, or if not on a selection
            Abort = True
            If Not KeyCode = 0 Then ' If on a selection past the first entry
                KeyCode = 0
            'Manually choose next entry, cancel key press
                ComboBox1.ListIndex = ComboBox.ListIndex - 1
            End If
            Me.ComboBox1.DropDown
        Case 40 'Down
            If ComboBox1.ListIndex = ComboBox1.ListCount - 1 Then KeyCode = 0
        ' This method was from the discussion I linked, prevents "falling off the bottom of the list"
            Abort = True
            If Not KeyCode = 0 Then ' If on a selection before the last entry
                KeyCode = 0
            'Manually choose next entry, cancel key press
                ComboBox1.ListIndex = ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1
            End If
            Me.ComboBox1.DropDown
    End Select
    Abort = False
End Sub
```

However, when I enter something (Let's say I enter "App" to find "Applesauce" and the dropdown list shows both "Apple" and "Applesauce") and click the down button, it just goes to the first item and does not move anymore. The list does not disappear but it just gets stuck on the first item.

*Does anyone have any idea what I need to change in my code to make it work? (Or any other ideas on how to make it work in general)?*

GIF for clarification:
[KeyDown not moving beyong first item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9X0Hr.gif)

Comment: Can you show the behavior by adding an image using “Screen to Gif”? Would help.

Comment: @Skin I added a GIF for clarification. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: I use the same code and it worked for me perfectly until some update of Office 365... :( It still works fine on Excel 2010 when I checked it on other computer. That update also broke 'search as you type' functionality in my ComboBox.